Calling mint_to for second times error: ConstraintMintMintAuthority. Error Number: 2016. Error Message: A mint mint authority constraint was violated
Initialize and Mint token functions:
pub fn init_token(ctx: Context<InitToken>, metadata: InitTokenParams) -> Result<()> {
        let authority = &ctx.accounts.payer;
        let seeds = &["mint".as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint]];
        let signer = [&seeds[..]];

        let account_info = vec![
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        ];

        let create_token_intrusion_meta_data = &CreateMetadataAccountV3 {
            metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            mint_authority: ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            update_authority: (ctx.accounts.mint.key(), false),
            payer: ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.key(),
            rent: Some(ctx.accounts.rent.key()),
        }.instruction(CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs {
            data: DataV2 {
                name: metadata.name,
                symbol: metadata.symbol,
                uri: metadata.uri,
                seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
                creators: None,
                collection: None,
                uses: None,
            },
            is_mutable: false,
            collection_details: None,
        });
        invoke_signed(
            create_token_intrusion_meta_data,
            account_info.as_slice(),
            &signer,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

pub fn buy_tokens(ctx: Context<BuyTokens>, quantity: u64) -> Result<()> {
        // Get the required accounts
        let user = &ctx.accounts.payer.key();
        // Construct the signer
        let seeds = &["mint".as_bytes(), &[ctx.bumps.mint]];
        let signer = [&seeds[..]];

        mint_to(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                MintTo {
                    authority: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.destination.to_account_info(),
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                },
                &signer,
            ),
            quantity,
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(params: InitTokenParams)]
pub struct InitToken<'info> {
    /// CHECK: New Metaplex Account being created
    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
      init,
      seeds = [b"mint"],
      bump,
      payer = payer,
      mint::decimals = params.decimals,
      mint::authority = mint,
  )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    /// CHECK: account constraint checked in account trait
    #[account(address = mpl_token_metadata::ID)]
    pub token_metadata_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct BuyTokens<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"mint"],
        bump,
        mint::authority = mint,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = payer,
    )]
    pub destination: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
}

I deploy the program and run this test:
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

describe("meme", async () => {
  // Constants from our program
  const MINT_SEED = "mint";
  const TOKEN_SEED = "token";
  const METADATA_SEED = "metadata";

  // Data for our tests
  const payer = provider.wallet.publicKey;
  let user = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
    "DRSmAfYUwovYnXpGLaJ6D8yXLDvJneC9aHRcEU8eYAZ7"
  );

  const [mint] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from(MINT_SEED)],
    pg.PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
      "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
    );

  const [metadataAddress] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from(METADATA_SEED),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mint.toBuffer(),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    );

  const metadata = {
    name: "My Test Token",
    symbol: "TESTING",
    uri: "https://5vfxc4tr6xoy23qefqbj4qx2adzkzapneebanhcalf7myvn5gzja.arweave.net/7UtxcnH13Y1uBCwCnkL6APKsge0hAgacQFl-zFW9NlI",
    decimals: 9,
  };


  // Test init token
  it("initialize", async () => {
    const info = await pg.connection.getAccountInfo(mint);

    if (info) {
      return; // Do not attempt to initialize if already initialized
    }
    console.log("  Mint not found. Attempting to initialize.");

    const context = {
      metadata: metadataAddress,
      mint,
      payer,
      rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      tokenProgram: anchor.utils.token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
    };

    const txHash = await pg.program.methods
      .initToken(metadata)
      .accounts(context)
      .rpc();

    await pg.connection.confirmTransaction(txHash, "finalized");
    console.log(`  https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txHash}?cluster=devnet`);
    const newInfo = await pg.connection.getAccountInfo(mint);
    assert(newInfo, "  Mint should be initialized.");
  });

  it("mint tokens", async () => {
    const destination = await anchor.utils.token.associatedAddress({
      mint: mint,
      owner: payer,
    });

    let initialBalance: number;
    try {
      const balance = await pg.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(destination);
      initialBalance = balance.value.uiAmount;
    } catch {
      // Token account not yet initiated has 0 balance
      initialBalance = 0;
    }

    const context = {
      mint,
      destination,
      payer,
      rent: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      tokenProgram: anchor.utils.token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      associatedTokenProgram: anchor.utils.token.ASSOCIATED_PROGRAM_ID,
    };

    const mintAmount = 10;
    const txHash = await pg.program.methods
      .buyTokens(new BN(mintAmount * 10 ** metadata.decimals))
      .accounts(context)
      .rpc();
    await pg.connection.confirmTransaction(txHash);
    console.log(`  https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txHash}?cluster=devnet`);

    const postBalance = (
      await pg.connection.getTokenAccountBalance(destination)
    ).value.uiAmount;
    console.log("Post balance :", postBalance);
    assert.equal(
      initialBalance + mintAmount,
      postBalance,
      "Post balance should equal initial plus mint amount"
    );
  });
});


It works correctly as expected. But when I run it the second time-onwards it gives me this error:
ConstraintMintMintAuthority. Error Number: 2016. Error Message: A mint mint authority constraint was violated.
